# Javascript memory leak in simple code

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I'm having some kind of memory problem in my javascript code.  I've been searching online for memory leak patterns in javascript, but none of the patterns seem to apply to my code.  It's very simple code, there are no closures, I don't even have internal functions, all my variables merely hold simple values, like DOM objects or booleans, I don't even define properties in my variables.  But yet somehow I manage to leak so much memory that Firefox (3.6.11) freezes and IE tells me I'm running out of memory at line 73, I've marked that line.  The functions to which there are references in the DOM tree are toggle, replyForm and replyExpand.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(expandable){
    if(expandable.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].className=="hide"){
        expandable.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].className="show";
        expandable.innerHTML="▼";
    }
    else{
        expandable.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].className="hide";
        expandable.innerHTML="►";
    }
}

var previousSpan;

function replyForm(span,postId,op,commentID){
    if(removeForm(span))
        return;
    previousSpan=span;

    if(span.nextSibling!=null){
        span.parentNode.insertBefore(form(span,postId,op,commentID),span.nextSibling);
    }
    else{
        span.parentNode.appendChild(form(span,postId,op,commentID));
    }
}

function removeForm(span){
    if(previousSpan==null)
        return false;  <-- Out of memory here according to IE
    if(previousSpan.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("form").length!=0)
previousSpan.parentNode.removeChild(span.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]);
    var result=(span==previousSpan);
    if(result)
        collapse(previousSpan);
previousSpan=null;
return result;
}

function form(span,postId,op,commentID){
var result=
"<form id=\"commentform\" method=\"post\" action=\"http://innategamer.300mb.us/wp-comments-post.php\">\n"+
"<p>Replying to "+op+":</p>\n"+
"<p><label for=\"author\">Name *</label><input id=\"author\" type=\"text\" aria-required=\"true\" size=\"30\" value=\"\" name=\"author\"></p>\n"+
"<p>Email *<input id=\"email\" type=\"text\" aria-required=\"true\" size=\"30\" value=\"\" name=\"email\"></p>\n"+
"<p>Website<input id=\"url\" type=\"text\" size=\"30\" value=\"\" name=\"url\"></p>\n"+
"<textarea id=\"comment\" aria-required=\"true\" rows=\"8\" cols=\"45\" name=\"comment\"></textarea>\n"+
"<input id=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Post Comment\" name=\"submit\">\n"+
"<input id=\"comment_post_ID\" type=\"hidden\" value=\""+postId+"\" name=\"comment_post_ID\">\n"+
"<input id=\"comment_parent\" type=\"hidden\" value=\""+commentID+"\" name=\"comment_parent\">\n"+
"</form>";
    var div=document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML=result;
    return div.firstChild;
}

function replyExpand(span){
    if(span.innerHTML.indexOf("▼")!=-1)
        collapse(span);
    else
        expand(span);
}

function collapse(span){
    if(previousSpan==span)
        removeForm(span);
    span.innerHTML=span.innerHTML.replace("▼","►");
    while(span.nextSibling!=null){
        span=span.nextSibling;
        if(span.className=="comment-content show");
            span.className="comment-content hide";
    }
}

function expand(span){
    span.innerHTML=span.innerHTML.replace("►","▼");
    while(span.nextSibling!=null){
        span=span.nextSibling;
        if(span.className=="comment-content hide");
            span.className="comment-content show";
    }
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd imagine it has something to do with the fact that these two functions call each other, and as a far as I can tell, the `if` statements, once true, will always be true.

```
function removeForm(span) {
    if (previousSpan == null) return false; < --Out of memory here according to IE
    if (previousSpan.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("form").length != 0)
        previousSpan.parentNode.removeChild(span.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]);
    var result = (span == previousSpan);
    if (result) collapse(previousSpan); // <---------------
    previousSpan = null;  //                               |
    return result;        //                               |
}                         //                               |
                          //                               |
function collapse(span) { //                               |
    if (previousSpan == span) removeForm(span); // <--------
    span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML.replace("▼", "►");
    while (span.nextSibling != null) {
        span = span.nextSibling;
        if (span.className == "comment-content show");
        span.className = "comment-content hide";
    }
}
```

Effectively:

```
var previousSpan;

function removeForm( span ) {
    // ...
    if( span == previousSpan ) collapse(previousSpan);
    // ...
}

function collapse( span ) {  // <---here span is previousSpan,
       // <-- always true because you're doing if(previousSpan == previousSpan)
    if (previousSpan == span) removeForm(span);   
    // ...
}

// This makes subsequent comparisons in "removeForm()" always true as well,
//    because now it is guaranteed that "span" is the same as "previousSpan"
```

So once `span == previousSpan` in `removeForm()`, you're passing `previousSpan` to `collapse()`. The first thing `collapse()` does is checks to see if what it received is equal to `previousSpan`, which it always will be since that was the test to send it in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, you're right again.  And I really feel stupid now.  Thanks for the help I really appreciate it.  I was looking at this code for hours yesterday and didn't see that.

Comment: Well, all of the answers I got were correct, I chose this one because it's contains some, well, 'graphic' and illustrates the problem.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an infinite loop going on in there.

`removeForm` calls `collapse`

`collapse` calls `removeForm`

Comment: Oh, shit, I think you're right!  How stupid I feel right now.  Thanks I'm glad you helped me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to take the time to go over this with a fine tooth comb.  But I do see `removeForm` calls `collapse`, which sometimes in turn calls `removeForm`.  The first thing I'm suspicious of is that these two functions are somehow calling each other in an infinite recursion pattern.

Please try putting break points at the beginning of one of these functions.

In your debugger, check the size of the call stack each time you hit a this break point.  If the call stack expands until the program runs out of memory, then congratulations, you have just posted a real Stack Overflow on StackOverflow!

Comment: You're right, although I actually looked at this code for several hours yesterday and I didn't spot that.  Now to choose the right answer, well all the answers are right so I'm just going to chose the answer that has the most text in it.

Comment: You can vote for posts that are helpful by clicking the "up" arrow next to the number to the left of the post.